# MSBuild error when building VC++ 2012 MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741502

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, teamcity

When building a sln file which only contains c++ projects using VS 2012 on TeamCity, I get the following error:

error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741502.

Does anyone know what does this error mean.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The exit code describes a STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED issue.